# Get items for today and yesterday based off timestamp

Tags: javascript, json, datetime

I have a json object which is generated using lowdb. Each json entry has a timestamp. I wan't to get all the entry for yesterday, and today based on the timestamp.

The items variable here is just a json object. Here is a sample

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "date": 1596131220030,
      "item": {
        "price": "160,00",
        "title": "Cotton Quarter-Zip Sweater"
      }
    },
    {
      "date": 1596232321030,
      "item": {
        "price": "160,00",
        "title": "Cotton Quarter-Zip Sweater"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the items from yesterday, and today in this functuin

```
export async function report(){
    try {
        const items = db.get('items').value();
        return items;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt to filter on date. You should try to solve this and then ask for help if it's not working.

Comment: Which database are you using? It sounds you might be able to filter per timestamp at `get` call site, or otherwise be able to filter the output using something like `Object.key(output.items).filter(({ date }) => new Date(date) > new Date(new Date().getTime() - (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))`

Comment: @MaximeHelen—there are much better ways to get a time value for yesterday. Not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed, and your method doesn't consider the current time.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare with time values for the start of "today" and "yesterday", e.g.

```js
// Return time value for the start of given date, default is today
function getToday(d = new Date()) {
  return new Date(+d).setHours(0,0,0,0);
}

// Return time value for the start of day prior to given day, default is today
function getYesterday(d = new Date()) {
  let e = new Date(getToday(d));
  return e.setDate(e.getDate() - 1);
}

let data = {
  "items": [
    {"date": 1596085802005, // 30 Jul 2020
     "item": "1"
    },
    {"date": 1596131220030, // 31 Jul 2020
     "item": "2"
    },
    {"date": 1596232321030, //  1 Aug 2020
     "item": "3"
    }
  ]
}

// Run as for 1 Aug 2020
let yesterday = getYesterday(new Date(2020,7,1));
let result = data.items.filter(item => item.date >= yesterday);
console.log(result);
```

Results may vary based on the host timezone offset as the above uses local date values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the date, and compare the difference as follows:

```js
let obj = {
  "items": [
    {
      "date": 1596131220030,
      "item": {
        "price": "160,00",
        "title": "Cotton Quarter-Zip Sweater"
      }
    },
    {
      "date": 1596232321030,
      "item": {
        "price": "160,00",
        "title": "Cotton Quarter-Zip Sweater"
      }
    }
  ]
};
let list = [];
let items = obj.items;
let today = new Date();
for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
     var d = new Date(items[i].date);
     var diff = Math.floor((d - today) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
     if(diff == 0 || diff == -1)
          list.push(items[i].item);
}
console.log(list);
```

Comment: A solution using `filter` might be cleaner (assuming there's no in-built DB filtering option available).

Comment: Doing `var today = new Date();` on every loop is wasteful and creates a date for the current date and time, whereas the OP likely wants to compare to a date at the start of the day.